# Usage of milestone

Tags: meaning, word-usage

A milestone is

> a significant event or stage in the life, progress, development, or the like of a person, nation, etc.

But does it also imply a chronological step? So does it make sense to say something like: "I suggest you get done with milestone 5 before you start milestone 2"

Comment: No, ***step*** is the proper term to use in that context.

Comment: ... 'Step 5 is a milestone round my neck.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as *satellite* means something different to an astronomer than to a layman, and *nun* has a much narrower definition in Catholicism than in general contexts, and *tap* refers to radically different concepts among plumbers, electricians, software developers, and entertainers, *milestone* is a term of art in the field of project management. Furthermore, *milestone* may have an even more restricted meaning within a particular organization, software package, or other context.

The [PM definition provided](http://technology.berkeley.edu/tpo/glossary) by the Technology Program Office of the University of California, Berkeley is reasonably common:

> a scheduled event signifying the completion of a major deliverable or a set of related deliverables.

A *milestone* in a business project therefore marks a common checkpoint for teams working on the project, where all their various tasks converge. In turn, passing a milestone indicates that the project has moved into a new phase.

There is an implication that milestones follow some sort of progression, and later milestones may have a dependency on earlier ones being achieved first. It is not necessary that this progression be strictly chronological, however, especially in some [agile methodologies](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/222504). Indeed, this is one reason some organizations use codenames instead of numbers or other labels indicating linear progress to mark their milestones. *The database team is ahead of schedule and already working toward Maple, so we are going to hold work on Birch and prioritize achieving Sycamore and then Maple*. Whether a "milestone 5" can ever come before a "milestone 2" is thus very dependent on the local context.

This is different from the more general understanding of *milestone*, as for instance [defined by Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/milestone):

> 1. a stone pillar that shows the distance in miles to or from a place
> 2. a significant event in life, history, etc

In the first, literal sense of the word, *milestones* do indeed follow a linear progression, but that is not the case in the common metaphorical meaning. It might be most common for someone to graduate from a university, get married, and buy a house, but there are many people who achieve these milestones in their life in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

Milestone long became a part of project manager lingo, where it is used exactly as you described. Milestone is a mark on a project plan, so it can be enumerated, put in a chronological order, etc.